# JQGrid: Select (that means highlight and check the checkbox) only on double click of a row, not on single click

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I am trying select (i.e. highlight and check the checkbox) only on double click of a row, not on single click. But not getting getting a clue how to achieve this.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution consist from 3 steps:

1. prevent default selection on click on the row
2. selection of row on double-click
3. preventing selection of the text in the cell on double-click

To prevent default selection one need include the following callback

```
beforeSelectRow: function () {
    return false; // prevent selection
}
```

To select on double-click one should call `setSelection` inside of `ondblClickRow` callback

```
ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
    $(this).jqGrid("setSelection", rowid);
}
```

To prevent selection of the text in the cell on double-click one need to add CSS rule like the following:

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow > td {
   -webkit-touch-callout: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew it will be YOU who can answer this and quickly. I tried everything except setSelection in ondblClickRow. To meet my requirement (i.e also to select a row by checking the checkbox) I added the below code and it is working. Could you please advice any better approach. if ( (e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() == "INPUT") && (clickedCellId.indexOf("jqg_grid1_") == 0) ) {
       return true;
      } else {
       return false;
      }

Comment: @Sudhir: You are welcome! I'm not sure what exactly you need to implement. What is `clickedCellId`? Do you use `multiselect: true`? Do you want allow to select by click on multiselect checkbox or on the cell with multiselect checkbox? In any way the usage of `.hasClass("cbox")` seems me better as `.indexOf("jqg_grid1_")`.

Comment: var clickedCellId = e.target.id;    yes, I use multiselect: true           Yes, I want to click multiselect checkbox (which appears at the begining of each row)

Comment: @Sudhir: Sorry, but you don't answered on my question whether the `beforeSelectRow` should be modified to allow to select on click on the **checkbox** from multiselect column or on click on **the cell** which contains the checkbox. The checkbox is smaller as the corresponding cell. In any way every behavior can be easy implemented. It would be probably better if you post *new question* with the code which you use and which works not exactly like you want. If you would describe exactly what you need I could modify your existing code.